# Cannot login to Azure VM SQL Server 2014 with a new login

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I have created a Virtual Machine Windows Server 2012 with SQL Server 2014. I have logged in successfully with the credentials I have specified during the VM install (Further referred as initial creds). I am experiencing the following two problems:

1. I cannot connect to the SQL remotely because of the Login failure.
2. I have created new SQL Server account/user called Test. Also, I have created DB1 database and made Test user an owner of this db. I have made DB1 a default db for that Test user. I cannot login to using Test account remotely, nor I cannot do so from the VM when remoting to it through the Remote Desktop. http://take.ms/dAxP7

The only way I CAN connect to the DB is through a remote connection to vm with initial creds. I have reset the password several times. The password is correct.

Comment: Windows server has one account and to login to sql you need to have different account or both can be same,so testuser scenario is not valid and you can't  use those credentials to login to vm

Comment: when sql says login failure,it is correct and we are wrong for sure.,This document deals with many scenarios.try going through it:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sql/virtual-machines-windows-sql-connect

Comment: The SQL Log records login failures with more detail than is reported to the user.

Comment: The strange fact is that when on my local machine I can add a user to my local db and then I can successfully login. Being on the VM remotely I cannot do the same. Anyway, I have VM main admin account that is added as admin in sql server. I can login with that account being on the VM remotely. When I try connecting to VM DB through my local SQL Management Studio it says that login failed. I suspect it has something to do with domain prefix. I am trying to access DB from my local machine using its (the VMs) IP address (I do not know any other name to access it by).

Comment: Can you post the error message? It will pop up if you click on the little icon at the bottom left of the error message?

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for trying to help me. I have resolved the issue. The problem was that I did not set SQL Authentication option to enabled when I was creating a sql VM instance. I could not find where I can change it once the VM instance is created. So, I have deleted the VM instance and created a new one with the option enabled. It works now. 
Here is the article where I fund about that option: [how to setup sql on azure VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sql/virtual-machines-windows-portal-sql-server-provision#SSMS). The DB was SQL Srv. Standard Edition. You will have to configure TCP for express and developer additions in addition to the option mentioned above.

Comment: You can change the SQL Server authentication mode after installation from SSMS. Right-click on the server in Object Explorer (Properties-->Security). The change will take affect after restarting the service.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue in desktop version.. created a login but can't login from SQL server management studio with that login..

The login need to be enabled for this from Security > Logins > right click and take Properties > Status tab

[image]